# Error while passing user data from model-controller to view using ion-auth in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

Here I am passing user related data like users first name and total points  according to username and password entered in login form. I am using ion-auth here for validating hashed passwords entered by user.
While receiving and viewing the user details in views I am facing the below error.
(Issue while passing user data from database through model to controller and finally to views)
Kindly guide me through right path as I am new to codeigniter and ion-auth.
Error:

```
  **Message: Undefined index: fname
  Filename: views/members_area.php**
```

My Membership_model and validate function:

```
function validate()
{
    $un=$this->input->post('username');
    $pw=$this->input->post('password');
    $this->db->where('username', $un);
    $query=$this->db->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    $this->load->ion_auth_model;
    $password_match=$this->ion_auth_model->hash_password_db($query->id,$pw);

        if($password_match !== FALSE)
        {               
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                $results[]= array(
                    'first_name'    => $rows->first_name,
                    'phone'         => $rows->phone,
                    'total_points'  => $rows->total_points,
                    );
            }

        return $results;
        }

    }

    else return false;
```

$results received from model is received by Login  contoller:

```
public function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('Membership_model');
    $query['result']=$this->Membership_model->validate();

    if($query) //if user credentials validated
    {           
        $this->load->view('members_area',$query);           
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "Login credentials doesn't match";
    }

}
```

This is where I am facing problem in views (members_area):

```
  <?php
        if(!empty($result))
    {
        foreach ($result as $key) {
        # code...
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $key['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['total_points']=$key['total_points'];
            $_SESSION['phone']=$key['phone'];

        }
        }
    ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id='game_zone'>
    <?php echo "<h1>Welcome ".$_SESSION['fname']."</h1>"; ?>
    <?php echo "<p>Your total points is <strong>".$_SESSION['total_points']."</strong></p>"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` or are you loading codeigniter's session library anywhere in your code?

Comment: No where I have mentioned the session_start(). If i start session again in any page I get error saying 'a session has already started' beacase here i h am using CI_bbotstrap3 template for admin panel and the login page i am facing problem is  for users only.  Kindly help.https://github.com/waifung0207/ci_bootstrap_3

Comment: the thing is that in your model $results[] array, you do not have an index 'fname', you have only a 'first_name'. So you are receiving warning, not an error with information that index which you are trying to call just not exists.

Comment: Validating credentials doesn't have anything to do with the error, so you can leave that bit out. The user is making it to the user area, so we assume that the validation part is fine. The bit that we do need to see isn't included. Need to look at what data is in $result. The short answer is that there is no first_name in there.